# how to deploy file with brackets in the name using workbench/ant package xml

Tags: metadata, ant, workbench

I have to profile layouts named with brackets in the name.
When retrieved the package xml have them listed as:

```
<members>My layout (version 1)</members><br/>
```

and the content of the layout folder lists as:

```
My layout %28version 1%29.layout
```

I am having problems with deploying the custom profiles. 
So far putting this variations into package.xml did not work

```
My layout %28;version 1%29.layout
My layout &#40;version 1&#41;.layout
My layout (version 1).layout
```

What should I put into package.xml to get them deployed? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you're pretty close with the first variation you tried, but you didn't need the ending `;`. Perhaps you've mistake the syntax for HTML entity escaping? In any case, it should be:

`My layout %28version 1%29.layout`

and not:

`My layout %28;version 1%29.layout`

Answer (score 0):

sorry ignore this it was windows saving my files with xml.txt. 
Please don't buy your developers this little devil's inventions.
the %28 version worked